# SQL Server Transactional Replication: Primary Key & Identity properties being dropped at Subscriber (sometimes)

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

I have set up a publication with multiple tables that obviously have a primary key. The PK is also an identity field that autoincrements by 1.

The "Copy Primary Key constraints" option is missing for my publication article options. I assume this is by design.

If I drop the tables from the Subscriber side and kick off replication to create the tables, the table is created but the PK is just an INT, no PK and no IDENTITY property.

If I create the table first on the subscriber side with the PK and IDENTITY assigned to the column, it works... sometimes. Not always.

This morning I created a publication with one of the "problem articles", created the Subscriber table, ran the agent and the PK/IDENTITY dropped. 2 hours later, same test (new subscription) - it ran fine with the PK/ID intact.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the value of the schema_option column for affected articles in sysarticles? You can look in [sp_addarticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addarticle-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for the decoder ring. Also, are you going to have an update-able subscriber? If not, the identity property doesn't matter much at the subscriber (as it won't be generating identity values).

Comment: This is exactly what the issue was (schema_option). I was experiencing the issue with the missing PK (sometimes) when I would use sp_addarticle without specifying the schema_option. I found that this would default to: 0x0000000000030073. 

When I went through the wizard, everything ran correctly and found that the schema_option was set to: 0x000000000803509F. 

I've gone ahead and added this to my script and things seem to work now.

Comment: Neat! In the spirit of letting your newfound knowledge help someone in the future, I'd encourage you to write up your findings as an answer to your own question. Specifically, which of the bits in the schema_option bitmask seemed to be the important ones?